# What principle of presence std::getline in std::string?

Tags: c++, inheritance, getline

I'm trying to figure out, paritcularly, where does class **std::string** get method **std::getline** from? It's said that this [method is non-member function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) of **std::string** and it's [overloaded in std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/). But where is commencement of getline existence? What order of getting it into **std::string** class? Is this method inherited from somewhere, or just presents in the file of class **std::string** in no man's land? Is it related to **getline** of **std::istream**? Is there some explicit description of inheritance structure of **std** classes? It would be convenient to contemplate such a structure of **std** lib. inheritance. Maybe it is in some documentation e. t. c.

Actualy there are two questions here:

1. Mechanism of `getline` appearance in connection to such things as inheritance
2. Overlook of `std` inheritance structure

Thanks!

Comment: [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is a freestanding template function declared in `<string>` header file.

Comment: the standard library uses inheritance sparingly. `std::istream` has a base class but other than that I already have to think for a while to find an example

Comment: I've just looked included file which I was conducted to from CodeBlocks right button pressing on **#include <string>**, and there are only **#include**-s and all. Why can't I see **std::getline** in there? Or it's some proprietary hiding?

Comment: On cppreference, a derived class has a graph describing the inheritance hierarchy upo near the top of the page. Example: [`std::fstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream). Not also a lot of the names you're used to are aliases for a longer, more precise name (and probably a template).

Comment: Standard library headers can get pretty insane. I get a bit lucky. The implementation I'm using left a handy comment: `#include <bits/localefwd.h>    // For operators >>, <<, and getline.`to help tracking down `getline`.

Comment: Marginally related: [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: Yes, I've seen `#include <bits/localefwd.h>    // For operators >>, <<, and getline` too. But the trace of implementation is being lost inside the **localefwd.h**

Comment: You might be confusing **overloading** with **_overriding_**. The two are very distinct features of C++. Overloading refers to having multiple functions with the same name that differ only by their argument types. Overriding refers to replacing the behaviour of a base class function in a derived class.

Comment: I understood that `getline` is not involved into *inheritance* at all, instead it's just a `function tamplate` simply pasted into file(`string` header) with appropriate content. Сorrect me if I wrong.

Comment: @Max That should be correct. Could be template specialization involved and hidden away somewhere, but I'd say you have the right of it in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where does class std::String

There is no class `std::String`. You may have intended to write `std::string` which does exist.

> get method std::getline from?

`std::string` doesn't have such member function. There is a free function (template) by that name instead.

> It's said that this method is non-member function of std::String and it's overloaded in std::String.

Saying those things would be wrong. `std::getline` is a non-member function (template) but it is not "of `std::String`". There was an overload introduced in C++11 overloading the istream parameter, but not "in `std::String`".

> But where is commencement of getline existence?

`std::getline` is defined in the standard header `<string>`.

> What order of getting it into std::String class?

It is not "in `std::String` class".

> Is this method inherited from somewhere

No.

> Is it related to getline of std::istream?

Not in the sense of C++ inhertiance. But they are functions that share the same name and which implement the same abstract concept. One reads any length of input into a resizable `std::string` and the other reads to any character buffer but only up to a constant size.

> Is there some explicit description of inheritance structure of std classes?

Yes. The standard document is the authoritative source that specifies which standard classes are guaranteed to inherit which.

Comment: Yes, I was completely sloppy when I was writing **std::String**, It's **std::string** ofcourse. Thank you for mend.